# Am I coding this powershell correctly? Because it does not do what I intended

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

Need to find out the document set name from a field name called "Region". I need to set the doc set name to be whatever Region is (NW, SW, NE, SE, etc.) and move files from root of the document library to it's respected doc set. I dont mind hard coding the site or web url and doc lib url. I am geting this error:

Missing expression after ','. At C:\PS\MoveFiles.ps1:13 char:59 + $list.Items.MoveTo($destinationFolderUrl + $file.Name, <<<< true); + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (,:String) [], ParseException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

```
#Setup default variables
$webUrl = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://CiscoIntranet/sites/VOIP"
$list = $webUrl.GetList("http://CiscoIntranet/sites/VOIP/ForwardTech")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(”Microsoft.SharePoint”) 

function ProcessMove {
   param($folderUrl)
   $folder = $web.GetFolder($folderUrl)
        foreach ($file in $folder.Files)
            {   
                $docset=$($file.Region);
                $destinationFolderUrl = "http://CiscoIntranet/sites/VOIP/ForwardTech/" + $docset;
                $list.Items.MoveTo($destinationFolderUrl + $file.Name, true);
                $webUrl.Update();
            }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual effect of the code?

Comment: Missing expression after ','.
At C:\PS\MoveFiles.ps1:13 char:59
+                 $list.Items.MoveTo($destinationFolderUrl + $file.Name, <<<<  true);
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (,:String) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

Comment: Your code and error don't match. Where is the `$file.Name` part in the code on line 13?

Comment: @manojlds: sorry, i updated the code.

Comment: Have you tried using `$true` instead of `true`

Comment: @JNK - just saw your comment. I got the same MissingExpressionAfterToken error after I replicated it. See my answer

Comment: @Jnk: I tried $true and did not work. I am now going to try what manoj is suggesting. Thanks

Comment: @Richard Gear - didn't work? Basically I suggested the same thing! What are you trying now that I "suggested"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code

```
$siteURL="http://Server"
$docLib = "My Doc Lib"
$site=Get-SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.RootWeb
$collFiles=$web.GetFolder($docLib).Files
$count=$collFiles.Count
while($count -ne 0)
{
$item = $collFiles[$count-1].Item
$DocSet = $item["Region"]
Write-Host "$DocSet is the doc set. $collFiles[$count-1].Name is name"
$collFiles[$count-1].MoveTo($siteURL + "/" + $docLib + "/" + $DocSet + "/"  + $collFiles[$count-1].Name, $true)                       
$count--
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The second parameter should be `$true` and not just true.

I replicated the same error as follows:

```
function fun($m,[bool]$f) {
      write-host $m $f
}

fun ("blah", true)
```

Weirdly, something like:

```
function fun([bool]$f) {
      write-host $m $f
}
fun (true)
```

gives an error like:

> fun : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'f'. Cannot
>   convert value "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject" to type
>   "System.Boolean", parameters of this type only accept booleans or
>   numbers, use $true, $false, 1 or 0 instead.

which is more descriptive and the solution is in the error message!

Comment: Manojlds: Let me try your solution

Comment: getting this error. You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PS\MoveFiles.ps1:8 char:28
+    $folder = $web.GetFolder <<<< ($folderUrl)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetFolder:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection] doesn't contain a method named 'MoveTo'.
At C:\PS\MoveFiles.ps1:13 char:23
+ $list.Items.MoveTo <<<< ($destinationFolderUrl + $file.Name, $true);
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MoveTo:String)

Comment: @Richard Gear - It is a whole different issue. Can you create a different question for that?